# NodeJS Express - Pending when downloading static files takes more than a minute

Tags: node.js, express

I have a NodeJS app using Express, which serves an Angular app. The App runs in cluster mode. When running it locally, it works like a charm.

I however have a production environment where I use docker to serve the application. When loading the page on the production environment, the page takes more than one minute to load certain static files:
[image: Download pending for more than a minute]

Eventually the page will load, but it takes way longer than it should. I'm wondering if there is something wrong with the server.js file, which is express app main file.

The server file is as follows:

```html
// Get dependencies
const cluster = require('cluster');
const numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length;

if (cluster.isMaster) {
    console.log(`Master ${process.pid} is running`);

    // Fork workers.
    for (let i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
        cluster.fork();
    }

    cluster.on('exit', (worker, code, signal) => {
        console.log(`worker ${worker.process.pid} died`);
        cluster.fork();
    });

    console.log("All workers started.");
}
else {
    const path = require('path');
    const https = require('https');
    const fs = require('fs');
    const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
    const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    const sslPrivateKey = fs.readFileSync('sslcert/cert.key', 'utf8');
    const sslCertificate = fs.readFileSync('sslcert/cert.crt', 'utf8');
    const sslCredentials = { key: sslPrivateKey, cert: sslCertificate, passphrase: 'v1nd1ct4' };
    const express = require('express');
    const compression = require('compression');
    // Get API controller in the form of an Express Router.
    const api = require('./api');
    const portalBackend = require('./portalBackend');

    // Express RequestHandlers.
    const authCallbackHandler = require('./requestHandlers/authCallbackHandler');
    const validateRequestHandler = require('./requestHandlers/validateRequest');
    const responseReadyHandler = require('./requestHandlers/responseReadyHandler');
    const app = express();
    app.use(compression());

    // Serve Angular files as static content.
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist'));

    // Enable the use of cookies.
    app.use(cookieParser());

    // Enable parsers.
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
    // Check if the request is valid.
    app.use(validateRequestHandler);


    // Let Express know of API routes.
    // Enable catching return from API controllers to handle setting new ID cookie.
    app.use('/portalapi', portalBackend, responseReadyHandler);

    app.use('/api', api, responseReadyHandler);

    // Check and handle the request if it originates from the IdentityServer.
    app.use(authCallbackHandler);

    // If no file or /api is matched, redirect to the homepage of the portal.
    app.all('/*', (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist'));
    });

    const port = process.env.PORT || '4200';
    app.set('port', port);

    const httpsServer = https.createServer(sslCredentials, app);
    httpsServer.listen(port, '0.0.0.0', () => console.log('HTTP Server listening to port: ' + port));

    console.log(`Worker ${process.pid} started`);
}
```

I'd love to hear if any of you have any idea about what could be wrong.